# Magento Login to Admin panel throws "Email already exists."

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I recently upgraded my Magento system to 1.7.2 and i had several problems.
Most of them were easy to fix but this one is hard.

My problem was that i couldn't log-in as a customer or as an admin to the panel except of 1 user.

So as i got an advice from the internet saying to flush the permission of the admin group.

I did that and now everytime i try to log in to gives me this exception:

> Email already exists.
>
> #0 /home/bellater/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(676): Mage::throwException('Email already e...')
>   #1 /home/bellater/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(424): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_checkUnique(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_User))
>   #2 /home/bellater/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_User))
>   #3 /home/bellater/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php(142): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
>   #4 /home/bellater/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php(95): Mage_Admin_Model_Session->refreshAcl()
>   #5 /home/bellater/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Admin_Model_Observer->actionPreDispatchAdmin(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>   #6 /home/bellater/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Observer), 'actionPreDispat...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>   #7 /home/bellater/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App-dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
>   #8 /home/bellater/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(528): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
>   #9 /home/bellater/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
>   #10 /home/bellater/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(408): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
>   #11 /home/bellater/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
>   #12 /home/bellater/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard-match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>   #13 /home/bellater/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>   #14 /home/bellater/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>   #15 /home/bellater/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
>   #16 {main}

can anyone help me please?

Comment: Not sure that this helps, but it's worth a try http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/locked-out-from-magento-admin/